# Pyinstaller - exe doing other things than Python scripts

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have a problem with pyinstaller and my program. If I start my script, everything runs correct, but if I run the exe, it's doing strange things.

This code should do something while showing a frame, if it's finished the frame should destroy. But in the exe it doesn't create anything, but after some time create a second main frame(nowhere in this script a main frame created, this just happens in the wxpython app).
Heres the code where the frame is created:

```
# self is a wx.Frame
def handleInputs(self):
    path = self.setSavePath() # setSavePath just takes a path from a fileDialog
    if path:
        self.dialog = WaitingDialog() # subclass of wx.MiniFrame
        self.dialog.Show(True)
        calcThread = threading.Thread(target=self.doStuff)
        checkThread = threading.Thread(target=self.checkFinishing)
        calcThread.start()
        checkThread.start()
        self.Disable()

def checkFinishing(self, thread):
    while thread.is_alive():
        pass
    wx.CallAfter(self.closeFrame)
    return True

def doStuff(self):
    # do Stuff here
    return True

def closeFrame(self):
    self.dialog.Destroy()
    self.Destroy()
```

so, self.handleInputs() is called, but in the app, it looks like nothing is done in the doStuff(), and then a new main frame is created. 
Do you see any mistake or know why this happens?

Comment: Information about how you're using pyinstaller will help, as would an SSSCE (http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.  As it stands, I can't reproduce your behavior using what you've provided.

Comment: Also, are you doing anything with multiprocessing anywhere in your app?  Is it possible that something that should be under an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block isn't properly indented?  PyInstaller's two-pass execution might be creating odd behaviors.

Comment: Thank you, solved it now, problem was multiprocessing. I removed all Processes and use Threads now, but its a bit slower now. Sorry if my example was a bit inconcrete, it was too late yesterday :( I will keep it in mind for the next time

Comment: Found this solution now: http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/Multiprocessing, but it's MUCH slower than working with Threads

Comment: I've personally had much better luck with py2exe than with pyinstaller.  The two-pass execution in pyinstaller kills performance, _especially_ for small, quick-running scripts.

Comment: Richard, if you can answer and accept your own answer for this question, it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now, removed all uses of multiprocessing.